# NSView embeded in NSScrollView does not redraw consistently

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview

I was hoping to figure out how to get my NSView to correctly re-size and re-draw it's elements but I've pulled too much hair out debugging my problem I thought it's time I ask.

**Problem**

My custom view FSNavigatorView draws an "icon" (which is an NSBezierPath stored in a mutable array) for each project item that was read in from a document.  The project item can range from just a few items to over 60 items depending on the document.  On window re-size the view is supposed to redraw the icons so they line up properly.  This worked before I had NSScrollView, but I don't want to make the end user have to re-size the window everytime they add more project items. With the NSScrollView, I can't get the NSView which is embeded inside it to redraw consistently.  I have attached images to demonstrate what I mean here.  The first is before I resize (i.e. open a document), the next is when I resize diagonally.[image][image: enter image description here]![enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdLwt.png)
As you can see in the images, when I diagonally resize, the NSView redraws once resulting in 4 columns instead of 3 but if I continue to pull increase the window size nothing happens.  Also, if I just horizontally resize after opening a document it won't redraw.

**Background**

I have a custom NSView called FSNavigatorView.  In my xib I have a window (FSProjectSpace which is a subclass of NSDocument) with a NSScrollView which contains an NSView (I tried doing the Editor->Embed In->Scroll View but that caused more damage than good).  I have two outlets in FSProjectSpace for the NSScrollView and the NSView (which is my custom FSNavigatorView).

**FSProjectSpace.h**

```
@property (readwrite, assign) IBOutlet FSNavigator *navigator;
@property (readwrite, assign) IBOutlet NSScrollView *scrollView;
```

**FSProjectSpace.m**

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController {
    [self.scrollView setDocument:self.navigator];
    [self.navigator setProjectData:project]; // this sets the project data which the navigator view uses to draw icons.
}
```

I have the custom NSView update the frame after notification from the superview of a resize because `[self inLiveResize]` doesn't work in the NSScrollView either.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.  I've just been googling/reading Apple docs all day long and haven't made any head way.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using NSCollectionView, it seems similar on the surface to what you need?

Comment: I did not know such thing existed.  Thank you! I will start reading up on that.  **EDIT** This is perfect, thank you!  It give me more flexibility than my NSView design attempt.

Comment: Great! The less code, the better!